# Check if a string is a Palindrome (using methods)

Tags: java, eclipse, string, methods, boolean

I have no idea why the following method is not working. It shows:

> Palindrome.java:97: error: `<identifier>` expected

The method takes a parameter which is a String and should return `true` or `false` if the provided String is a palindrome.

```
public static boolean checkPalindrome(checkString) {
    boolean test = true;
    int left = 0;
    int right = checkString.length() - 1;
    while (left < right && test) {
        if (checkString.charAt(left) != checkString.charAt(right)) {
            test = false;
        }
        right--;
        left++;
    }
    return test;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What does it do that it isn't supposed to do? Any errors?

Comment: When you posted the question, you didn't have datatype in your method. Was that a typo?

Comment: @Tunaki You are not supposed to change the source except for indentation. You just removed the cause of the problem.

Comment: @RealSkeptic God you're right... I formatted it properly in my IDE, which auto-corrected the mistake... Didn't even notice it, thinking it was a typo

Comment: actually it wasn't a typo you guys  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mistake in the first line , it should be :

```
public static boolean checkPalindrome(String checkString)
```

you have to provide the data type before the parameter ^

Answer (score 3):

Problem is this line

```
public static boolean checkPalindrome(checkString)
```

Should be

```
public static boolean checkPalindrome(String checkString)
```

Just a suggestion but you can also reduce the variables that you are using

```
int len = checkString.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
    if (checkString.charAt(i) != checkString.charAt(len - i -1)) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Efficient? No as this for loop as well as your while loop iterates until `length/2`. Readable? Yes

Answer (score 3):

I think you made a mistake in the first line , it should be :

```
public static boolean checkPalindrome(String checkString)
```

you have to provide the data type before the parameter  ^